# .NET 7 Web Application sending an HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-applications

I know there's a lot of topics with the same error message, to be honest, I tried many of them, but none has worked so far, that's why I'm creating this post.

I'm trying to publish a .NET 7 web application, developed with Visual Studio 2022, on an IIS server.
The configuration on my IIS server seems good, because I've tested it with a simple web application, the one we get after creating a new VS file, and it's working.

So I'm thinking about a problem with the configuration of the application itself.

Here is the Program.cs file:

```
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using NewJoinersWebApp.Data;
    using NewJoinersWebApp.Models;
    using Rotativa.AspNetCore;
    
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
    
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    
    //this is to configure the DbContext for LoginUser interface
    //builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContextLoginUser>(options =>
    //options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    //builder.Services.AddIdentity<LoginUsers, Role>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContextLoginUser>();
    
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    
    app.UseRotativa();
    
    
    app.UseRouting();
    
    //add the control on the Http server
    //app.UseAuthentication();
    
    app.UseAuthorization();
    
    //app.MapFallbackToFile("/NotFound", "NotFound.html");
    
    app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        
    app.Run();
```

*Edit: I've removed the unnecessary `class Startup`*
And here is the csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameWorkCore" Version="7.0.11" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.11">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="7.0.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Rotativa.AspNetCore" Version="1.3.2-beta" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I've checked them several times, I've compared them with the basic application that works, but all I tried didn't work.

I desperately get the following webpage error message:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list
> the contents of this directory.
>
> Most likely causes: A default document is not configured for the
> requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.
>
> Things you can try: If you do not want to enable directory browsing,
> ensure that a default document is configured and that the file exists.
> Enable directory browsing using IIS Manager. Open IIS Manager. In the
> Features view, double-click Directory Browsing. On the Directory
> Browsing page, in the Actions pane, click Enable. Verify that the
> configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is
> set to true in the site or application configuration file.
>
> Detailed Error Information: Module       DirectoryListingModule
> Notification     ExecuteRequestHandler Handler       StaticFile Error
> Code     0x00000000 Requested URL    http://localhost:8282/ Physical
> Path     C:\inetpub\wwwroot\NewJoinersWebApp.site Logon Method
> Anonymous Logon User     Anonymous
>
> More Information: This error occurs when a document is not specified
> in the URL, no default document is specified for the Web site or
> application, and directory listing is not enabled for the Web site or
> application. This setting may be disabled on purpose to secure the
> contents of the server. View more information »

Of course, changing the config in the IIS server to allow the server *to list the contents of this directory* is not the solution.

The *Default Document* configuration is the classic one, and in the folder created when publishing the application there no standard files like *index.html* or *default.htm*.

It looks like:

[image: The folder created when publishing the application from VS to the IIS server]

Is there something I've done wrong, or a thing I missed?

Thanks for any support you could grant.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\bin\NewJoinersWebApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You have redundant startup code-paths, I think ASP.NET is using your `class Startup` instead of your _top-level program_. Remove one or the other.

Comment: @Dai The `class Startup` was just for testing purpose, but even when removed, the issue remains the same...

Comment: can't find it, where it is?

Comment: You need that file in order to make ASP.NET Core work in IIS, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: You didn't even publish the artifacts for IIS deployment (learn `dotnet publish`)?

Comment: @Dai I don't know how to fill the web.config file, but it doesn't seem to be useful, and my test application is working fine without it. but I can try this track...

Comment: You're able to test locally without issues because ASP.NET Core can use its own mini-web-server when you run it locally - but when you deploy it to IIS you need to upload additional supporting files.

Comment: no, it's not working locally on the IIS server with my main application, it's only working with a simple testing application, the one we get when creating a default web application with Visual Studio

Comment: @Dai here is the web.config file: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.webServer>
   <handlers>
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
   </handlers>
   <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet"
      arguments=".\bin\NewJoinersWebApp.dll"
      stdoutLogEnabled="false"
      stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
      hostingModel="inprocess" />
  </system.webServer>
 </location>
</configuration>`

Comment: @Hakeem Do you have access to the IIS Administration console?

Comment: @Dai Yes I do, I have admin rights on IIS server

Comment: Use IIS' Failed Request Tracing to find out what's going on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/troubleshoot-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85 (the article was written for IIS 8.5, which is basically identical to IIS 10 as far as FRT is concerned).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257285/discussion-between-hakeem-and-dai).

Comment: It's 02:45am - lolno

Comment: sorry just clicked by accident :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enable the Directory Browsing feature to slove this issue:

1. Start IIS Manager. To do it, select Start, select Run, type inetmgr.exe, and then select OK.
2. In IIS Manager, expand server name, expand Web sites, and then select the website that you want to change.
3. In the Features view, double-click Directory Browsing.
4. In the Actions pane, select Enable.

Comment: I've put in my question that this option doesn't think the problem, it's not link with browsing the directory, browsing it, just allows me to browse it, not to run the web app

Comment: The problem is that the OP doesn't have a `web.config` file, so their IIS isn't configured to load ASP.NET Core applications at all - the message about directory-browsing is just a red-herring.

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see details about 403.14 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.